# How to change only last parameter of url using javascript instead of appending to it

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list which selected value I want to add as last parameter.

Example:

on page: site/nl/projecten

I select option with value : 'Makelaardij'

Then url needs to be site/nl/projecten/Makelaardij

This works with below code:

```
const projectFilter = document.querySelector('#projectFilter');
projectFilter.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    location.href = 'projecten/' + event.target.value;
});
```

But this keeps adding `projecten` when selecting a new value. Example:

website.nl/nl/projecten/projecten/Makelaardij

So I tried adding a slash before like this:

`location.href = '/projecten/' + event.target.value;`

But this removes the language part of the url and I get this:

website.nl/projecten/Makelaardij

What can I do to only change the last part everytime a new value is selected?

Current code:

```
const projectFilter = document.querySelector('#projectFilter');
projectFilter.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let baseUrl = location.href.split('/projecten/')[0];
    location.href = baseUrl + '/projecten/' + event.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first retrieve what is before `/projecten/` and then append to it :

```
let baseUrl = location.href.split(/\/projecten\/?/)[0];

location.href = baseUrl + '/projecten/' + event.target.value;
```

if there is no `/projecten/` in the url, it will add it, for example if the url is `site/nl` it will become `site/nl/projecten/Makelaardij` or whatever value was in the select

Also if the url is wrong : `website.nl/nl/projecten/projecten/Makelaardij` it will fix it into `website.nl/nl/projecten/Makelaardij`

Comment: I deleted my last comment because I see it also happens locally. /projecten keeps getting appended. I added my current code to my question. If I am at: `http://website.nl.test/nl/projecten` and pick an option, it goes to: `http://website.nl.test/nl/projecten/projecten/Makelaardij`

Comment: i updated my answer to make the last / optional, now it should work for `/projecten/` and `/projecten`

Answer (score 0):

Try split -> Replace -> Join

```
var x = location.href.split("/")
x[x.length - 1] = event.target.value
location.href = x.join("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it this way,

**location.origin**

Returns a string containing the canonical form of the origin of the specific location.

*e.g. `https://website.nl`*

now add the pathname: `/nl/projecten/`

result: `https://website.nl/nl/projecten/`

```
const projectFilter = document.querySelector('#projectFilter');
projectFilter.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    location.href = location.origin + "/nl/projecten/" + event.target.value;
});
```

checkout mdn documentation about location.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location